# Flutter Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1 while build apk

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-studio, dart

```
PS C:\flutter projeleri\firebase> flutter build apk
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64, android-x64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
    To generate an app bundle, run:
        flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
        Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
    To split the APKs per ABI, run:
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
        Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                
Parameter format not correct -
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.7.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not delete old C:\flutter projeleri\firebase\build\app\reports\lint-results-release-fatal.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 10m 37s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     641,3s (!)
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

**what's the problem?**

Answer (score 0):

first delete your build folder and use this command in terminal

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```